# Can I use "let" in react function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am studying React currently.

Can I use "let" in function component instead of using "useState" ?

```
const Func = () => {
  let fruit = "banana";

  const changeFruit = () => {
    fruit = "apple"
  };

  changeFruit();
}
```

```
const Func = () => {
  const [fruit, setFruit] = useState("banana");

  const changeFruit = () => {
    setFruit("apple");
  };

  changeFruit();
}
```

Comment: In a word, no. Your component won't rerender when the let value changes. Calling the set function returned by `useState` is how React knows to rerender the functional component.

Comment: `let` has nothing to do with `useState`. Your question is about the impact of removing `useState` and nothing to do with let.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a functional component, as a functional component has to return a React Element.

If it would be a functional component, and you change the variable *synchronously* before returning the Element, it's fine:

```
const Func = () => {
  let fruit = "banana";

  const changeFruit = () => {
    fruit = "apple"
  };

  changeFruit();

  return <>{fruit}</>; // displays "apple"
};
```

If you change it *asynchronously*, e.g.

```
  setTimeout(changeFruit, 1000);
```

then the component *won't rerender* after the variable changed. That's not what you want usually. If you `useState` and call the `setFruit` function, the component rerenders.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me  the meaning of a functional component and how setState behave in it.

Answer (score 2):

**Can I use "let" in function component instead of using "useState" ?**

The answer is No, you can't use let instead of state. Your component won't re-render, that's what state is all about

Please consider [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) docs to help you understand the concept of state in React

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. This document really helps me.